# Trouble reading floating point number from file

Tags: matlab

I am using the "textread" function to read a file like this:

```
[files1,time_in1,time_out1,lable_id1] = textread(ref_file,'%s%f%f%s%*[^\n]','delimiter',' ');
```

ref_file shows as next:

```
ACCEDE00000 0 10 sn
ACCEDE00100 0 5 sn
ACCEDE00300 0 10 sn
```

The console throws the next error:

```
Error using dataread
Trouble reading floating point number from file (row 3, field 3) ==> sn\n
```

I don't understand why shows this error. I think that the format is correct: I have a string in the last position of the line (%s) but Matlab read it like a float. Also, in the above lines reads the string correctly.

Can anybody help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your current `format` to

```
[files1,time_in1,time_out1,lable_id1] = textread(ref_file,'%s %f %f %s');
```

and it's recommended to use `textscan`, because `textread` is deprecated. The new code would be something like this

```
fileID = fopen(ref_file);
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f %f %s');
files1=C{1};
time_in1=C{2};
time_out1=C{3};
lable_id1=C{4};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `*[^\n]`, you should not need to add a specifier for newline, and what you're doing is asking it to look for a string that's not \n (five values, not four), so it's probably hopping to the next line and taking the first string, resulting in the second value (number) there being read as a string, and so on, until it tries to read one of the strings as a float.

If you need to, you can use `'endofline'` parameter but it should be able to figure out endofline by itself unless you're using something really non-standard.

side note: `textread` is now non-recommended and you should really use `textscan` instead.